# MoviePy: Using alpha layer in VideoFile not possible?

Tags: python, moviepy

I am creating some clips using `VideoClip(make=m(t))`.

Which works fine, however:

- If the images created by the `make` function, were to have an alpha layer and therefore consist of `(4, 1080, 1920)` metrics, moviepy will crash.

I get an error telling me, the dimensions were illegtimate.
I've tried researching the problem, but unfortunately without any proper answer or documentation hinting on what to do.
Of course I can use some sort of greenscreen hack, but that will 10x the time it takes for rendering.

So my question, is: Is it possible to use `"RGBA"` images for the `VideoClip` class, or am I to fork moviepy instead if I want a proper solution?